# Autofill with LinkedIn form

Tags: wordpress, forms, linkedin-api, autofill, hubspot

I have applied the Linked Autofill function but I have 2 questions about it:

1. **Here is the page link** : The page is hosted on HubSpot CMS - https://inboundmarketing.inboundmantra.com/inbound-marketing-company-contact-inbound-mantra

Here is code of the linkedIn autofill button for the above page:

```
<button id="autofill-button">
    <span class="logo">IN</span>
    <div class="button-text-container">
      <span class="button-text">
        AutoFill with <strong>LinkedIn</strong>
      </span>
    </div>
</button>

<style>
#autofill-button {
    height: 33px;
    width: 174px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px #2D6FA8 solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #79adcb;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #79adcb 15%, #2373ac 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #79adcb 15%, #2373ac 100%);
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#autofill-button:hover {
    background: #5a8193;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5a8193 15%, #1e4d72 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5a8193 15%, #1e4d72 100%);
}
#autofill-button:active {
    background: #1e4d72;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e4d72 15%, #5a8193 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e4d72 15%, #5a8193 100%);
}
#autofill-button .logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 34px;
    color: transparent;
    background: url(https://www.linkedin.com/scds/common/u/img/sprite/sprite_connect_v13.png) no-repeat scroll 0 -347px transparent;
}
#autofill-button .button-text-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 171px;
    height: 33px;
}
#autofill-button .button-text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
span.IN-widget {
    height: 0 !important;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>

<script>
    $('#autofill-button').click(function(){
    $('span.IN-widget *').click();
});
</script>

<script type="in/Login"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">// <![CDATA[
api_key: 81ndwffuhqmres
        authorize: false
        lang: en_US
</script>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
var callbackScope, extraData;
    function callback(args) {
        var fields = ['first-name', 'last-name', 'email-address', 'id', 'headline', 'pictureUrl', 'positions', 'num-connections'];
        IN.API.Profile("me").fields(fields).result(function(profiles) {
            member = profiles.values[0];
            console.log(member);
            $('[id*="firstname"]').val(member.firstName);
            $('[id*="lastname"]').val(member.lastName);
            $('[id*="email"]').val(member.emailAddress);
            $('#headline').val(member.headline);
            $('#picture').attr("src", member.pictureUrl);
            var i = 0;
            for (position of member.positions.values) {
                $('#position' + (i++)).val(position.company.name + " - " + position.title);
            }
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
    IN.Event.on(IN, 'auth', callback, callbackScope, extraData);
},500);
</script>
```

*There are entire fields autofilled but the phone number field is not working.*

2. This code is not working when I'm running this code in WordPress.

**Here is the page link** : https://www.inboundmantra.com/predictive-lead-scoring

***Please let me know how to fix it.***

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

have you whitelisted your domain? you need to contact a linkedin representative to whitelist your domain in order to use this feature.

Comment: Yes,  we have whitelisted for this feature. In our form the rest of the fields are worked, but only contact field is not working.